# Virtuemart - Tie in API function on checkout

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

What I am trying to do is once the user checks out, say he buy's $25 worth of points; I need to send a message to an API that the user made purchases worth $25 dollars.

I found the file, `checkout.thankyou.tpl.php`, where the confirmation message is given after all goes well. This is where I am going to tie in the API function.

My question is how do I get the amount that the user just purchased? From the page mentioned above, I need to access the total amount that the user just spent. Is it stored in a global variable? Is it still accessible? I will appreciate any ideas that you may have.

Answer (score 0):

On this last step of the checkout ps_checkout->add() is called to add the shopping cart items into the database, but the same function sends the notification email and clears the cart from the session. What you could do is:

- Use a system plugin onAfterInitialise that looks for the option/task that triggers the last checkout step
- recalculate the cart total from the $_SESSION, you also need to initialise the virtuemart session, have a look at virtuemart.php
- store your result temporarily in a different $_SESSION variable
- same plugin, check for loading of the thank you page and check for your variable in the session. Then trigger your API.

Comment: there is variable $user, wouldn't it help?